# Paypal Recurring Payment Negative Testing

Tags: testing, paypal, payment, recurring

I am developing recurring payments using PayPal Pro and the NVP APIs.  I have read here: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_recurringbilling_guide.pdf that negative testing should work with recurring payments.  I have my profile setup to allow for negative testing.

I am looking cause my initial payment to fail.  To do this I have set my AMT and INITAMT to 2010.  According to the documentation, I thought this would cause a payment failure, but instead the initial payment is successful.

Has anyone got negative testing with recurring payments to work?  For either the scheduled payment or the initial Payment?  If so, could you please provide any steps and/or tips?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
PARTNER=PayPal
PWD=yourpass
VENDOR=yourvendor
USER=youruser
ACTION=A
TENDER=C
ACCT=5105105105105100
EXPDATE=0115
TRXTYPE=R
PROFILENAME=MonthlySubscription
AMT=50000
START=12122013
PAYPERIOD=MONT
TERM=12
OPTIONALTRX=S
OPTIONALTRXAMT=2000.00
COMMENT1=First Time Customer
```

Having the OPTIONALTRXAMT=2000 will trigger a decline, or any code you need.